# Unusual indexing issue with selenium text selecting

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, microsoft-edge

Iam selenium to practice web scraping and extract the names + Twitter @'s for the top 100 universities in the UK using this site https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/top-100-most-influential-uk-and-us-universities-on-twitter/2013373.article. I've got it to work as I want however, the site is a bit unusual and has sorted there sections for each row for every university in these "tr" tags, so instead I get them by class name, however, this is also named weird and they are named "odd" "even" one after another nevertheless I've used this and got it to work. But I've noticed when I try to index the first item in the elementsEven, it gives me "indexofofrangeerror", however when I do print(elementsEven[0]) it's showing me an output. Then I figured I have to start from index 3, but why is this, why isnt it letting me start from 0, even when it is telling me via a print statement it has info there? does anyone know?

```
import csv
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions # Microsoft Edge 

# Get edge chromium
options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
driver = Edge(executable_path='./edgedriver_win32/msedgedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get("https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/top-100-most-influential-uk-and-us-universities-on-twitter/2013373.article")


elementsOdd = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("odd")
elementsEven = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("even")

card = elementsOdd[49] # FROM 0 TO 49

# Gets university name\n@tag, so we need to split by \n
text = card.find_elements_by_xpath("./td[1]/strong")[0].text
split_text = text.split("\n")
university_name, university_twitter_tag = split_text[0], split_text[1]

print(university_name + " " + university_twitter_tag)


card2 = elementsEven[3] # 3 FROM UP TO 51

# Gets university name\n@tag, so we need to split by \n
text2 = card2.find_elements_by_xpath("./td[1]/strong")[0].text

split_text2 = text2.split("\n")
university_name2, university_twitter_tag2 = split_text2[0], split_text2[1]

print(university_name2 + " " + university_twitter_tag2)
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So iam just trying to scrape the university official name e.g lincoln and there @twitterhandle for the top 100 in the uk

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the `tr` tags with their `class-name`. When you are trying use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("even")`, it returns any tag which contains class name - `even`.

And the first element that is `elementsEven[0]` is a `div` tag.

```
<div class="field-item even">
    <h2 class="standfirst">
        Most universities in the UK and the US now have a presence on Twitter, but which institutions can claim to be using the micro-blogging social network most effectively?
    </h2>
</div>
```

You can check the same with below line:

```
card2 = elementsEven[0] # You can try for other index elements.
print(card2.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

```
<h2 class="standfirst">Most universities in the UK and the US now have a presence on Twitter, but which institutions can claim to be using the micro-blogging social network most effectively?</h2>
```

To know the elements which has `even` in their class name, try with below xpath in the DOM. Its highlighting 103 elements.

```
//*[contains(@class,'even')]
```

If you want to extract details with the right index, use unique locators.

```
elementsEven = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[class=even]")
or 
elementsEven = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='even']")
card2 = elementsEven[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the "list index out of range" error is pointing to this line:

```
text2 = card2.find_elements_by_xpath("./td[1]/strong")[0].text
```

`card2 = elementsEven[0]` doesn't have an error, so `print(elementsEven[0])` will show an output.

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name("even")` will find all the elements containing `even` class. The first element contains `even` class is showing in the following screenshot. You can also check it using browser's F12 dev tools:

[image]

You can see that there's no `<td>` and `<strong>` in this element, so `card2.find_elements_by_xpath("./td[1]/strong")[0].text` will show the error.

The first `<tr>` with class `even` is the 3rd element of `elementsEven`, so we can get it by `elementsEven[2]`.